# ng2-datepicker all-label customization

Tags: angular, customization, ng2-datepicker

I'm using ng2-datepicker. I found out how to customize the language for the date-related content, but not for the "Select Year", "Today" and "Apply" buttons. I ended up changing the package's files, but this is more than ugly. Does somebody know a more beautiful solution or is it just not supported?

Comment: It looks like it is hardcoded. Perhaps raise an issue on the github page https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker/issues

Comment: Thank you for your answer and tip :) I raised this issue: https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-datepicker/issues/162